# Hide interface while printing in power apps custom form

Tags: powerapps

Print layout is applied to my custom Power Apps page.
When I try to print I see Power Apps interface.
Is it possible to hide those elements?

I saw information about print function limitations - [The Print function currently doesn't work on custom pages or embedded scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-print#known-limitations). But actually printing is working, so may be it is outdated information. That is way I am asking this question.

[image]

Comment: Did you embed canvas app inside model driven app?

Comment: @DikshaPoddar I added custom canvas page in my model-driven app